# Python script not running in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, python

Logged in as a regular user trying to schedule a cron job to run every minute on RHEL8. Python script runs fine when executed at terminal as ./python.py but giving me an error when run as a job in crontab. Below are the absolute paths, got by "which python3" and "realpath -e python.py". given chmod 777 permissions to python.py.

crontab -e

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3   /home/user/test_1/test/python.py >>  /home/user/test_1/test/cron.log 2>&1
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/user/test_1/test/python.py", line 127, in <module>
 log_location = config.log_file_location()
File "/home/user/test_1/test/config.py", line 62, in log_file_location
 baseLoc = self.base_data_location()
File "/home/user/test_1/test/config.py", line 56, in base_data_location
 baseDirPath = self.cb_config.get('base_data_dir', '/tmp')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception reading config: No section: 'test_connection'
Exception reading config: No section: 'product_info'
Exception reading config: No section: 'event_ids
```

Comment: Why are you using an explicit interpreter in the scheduled job, but not when you run it in an interactive shell? Try removing the `/usr/bin/python3` in front of `/home/user/test_1/test/python.py` and let the script decide what interpreter to use through its `#!`-line.  This may matter if you have multiple Python interpreters installed.

Comment: Hi, tried putting together as cron_script.sh

#!/usr/bin/env python3
  /home/user/Test_01/Test/python.py

Getting error:
[user@W-Test_01 Test]$ ./cron-script.sh
  File "./cron-script.sh", line 3
    /home/user/Test_01/Test/python.py (syntax error pointing to start of python.py path)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

This script probably depends on a shell environment variable which is set in your interactive shell but not in the `cron` environment. I'm betting that base_data_location() invokes `os.environ.get(<some variable>)` and that's not being defined in your `cron` context.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.